# Some intuition behind why we visit $\frac{2}{3}$ of Natural Numbers?

Tags: probability, statistics

Consider stating at $0$ on the number line of integers. Toss a fair coin and if heads advance $1$ space and if tails advance $2$ spaces.

1. What number has the highest probability of being visited?
2. What is the probability of visiting very large numbers roughly?

**First part**

The following recursive equation can be formed quite nicely conditioning on the first toss: $p_n = \frac{1}{2} p_{n-1} + \frac{1}{2}p_{n-2}$ (for $n \geq 3)$

In other words $p_n$ is the average of $p_{n-1}$ and $p_{n-2}$.

The average of $n$ values is less than or equal to the maximum of the values. Hence, for example, $10$ cannot be the most probably visited square because you visit either $8$ or $9$ with greater probability.

Likewise $9$ cannot be for the same logic continuing until we see $3$ cannot be. Hence the only candidates are $1$ or $2$.

The probability of visiting $1$ is $\frac{1}{2}$ and the probability of visiting $2$ is $\frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} = \frac{3}{4} $

Hence $2$ is the most probably visited square.

**Second part**

Solving the recurrence relation formed in the first part (using the intials $p_1$ and $p_2$ )  yields: $p_n = \frac{2}{3} + \frac{1}{3} \cdot (-\frac{1}{2})^n$

This explains the periodicity noticed prior and gives us the long-run average probability  of $\frac{2}{3}$

This number seems way to high for my intuition. I expected it to be $\frac{1}{2} $ can someone provide some intuition behind $\frac{2}{3}$?

Comment: There's an argument for 0 being the answer to the first question ^_^

Comment: @BrianMoehring lol indeed!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The intuition behind it is very simple: the average step length is $\frac32$. Therefore you would expect to traverse a stretch of length $n$ in about $\frac{n}{3/2}=\frac23 n$ steps. So about $\frac23$ of the integers in that stretch will be visited.

Comment: Gosh this was lovely. Wish I zoomed out a bit and found this for myself before posting on here! Lesson to be learned

Answer (score 3):

The only way for $n$ to be missed is for $n-1$ to be hit and then get a tails. So $$1-p_n=\frac12 p_{n-1}.$$ If $p$ is the limit, rhen $$1-p=\frac12p$$ or $p=\frac23.$

Another way of looking at it is that if $n$ is missed, the $n-1$ and $n+1$ are hit. On the other hand, it is possible for three numbers in a row to be hit.

A more intuitive approach. For any three consecutive values $n,n+1,n+2$ you can have, with $H$ meaning hit and $M$ meaning miss:

$$HHH, HHM,HMH,MHH,MHM.$$

Ten of those are $H$ and five of them are $M.$ This is hard to make formal, since these five cases are not equally likely, but it gets at the error in thinking the probability is $1/2.$

Comment: Thank you for this Thomas! A very nice approach!

Comment: I like the last part a lot.